# .NET desktop app to run on all screen size

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, size, screen

I have to develop an .NET app using C# that runs on all screen size(8", 10, 14, 22, etc). So whatever is the screen size, the app should work & dispaly properly.

How should I start up with this ? With this in mind I believe using WPF would be the best rather than WinForms (Pls correct if I am wrong). I can give weight to each component & text size and handle that but what about the actual window size. That height & width I can't define a number (like 300*250) or so. Window size shoula also be based on the screen size.

Can anyone help me know how do I work out with this. WPF or WinFroms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative size/location instead of absolute (example -> Use Grid.RowDefinition = */Auto, instead of fixed size, Use stackpanel, use dock panel)

[Automatic layout overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748828.aspx)

[Resolution independent or monitor size independent WPF apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897849/resolution-independent-or-monitor-size-independent-wpf-apps)

[Same question on MSDN with links in answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/wpf/thread/d76685d3-d2de-495e-bcb8-77ccd948a0ab)

Metro Apps are supposed to run on different form factors. You can look at [Guidelines for the different form factors on metro UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465400.aspx). It will help in understanding the challenges, and how to plan/resolve these challenges.

Comment: If I want to deisgn something like Metro UI, intially 6 grids (buttons) (MAIN UI), on clicking 1 btn screen 1 comes up, then again Main UI, again on clicking other btn, other screen comes up & again Main UI. How can this be designed using WPF ?

Comment: this can be achieved using NavigationWindow and creating different pages. One Master page with grid, other detail page.

Comment: In Window tag, have assigned MinWidth & MinHeight as 300, Height & Width as Auto. Have added a Grid with 2 cols & 3 rows ColumnDefinition Width="*" & RowDefinition Height="*". And finally added 4 btns - <Button Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Exit</Button> . I want to give the dpi value or so for btns which will make it bigger in size. How do I give that ?

Comment: dpi is a system level setting. Go through [Resolution independence](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-wpf/9781430272052/introducing-wpf/resolution_independence#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0MzAyNzIwNTIvNw==) section of Pro WPF in c# 4.0. It explains dpi, how WPF handles them, and how to change in Win 7/xp

Comment: I want to use TabControl. Does that also support resolution like Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, etc ? Or any other way to implement the same.

Comment: WPF uses vector graphics (except images/videos) thus it should be possible with all the controls. I have not used TabControl, but there must be some way. Note that by changing the DPI/resolution, size of app will surely change. What you need is to take care of layout.