# Resolution on my laptop and pc for my program

Tags: c++, forms, resolution

I have a little problem in C + + Windows Forms. When I made that small little program I did at 1280x1024 resolution, my computer see perfectly. When I installed on my laptop that has 1600x900 resolution not see the buttons down, meaning the option and exit button. How can I do to show well on all screens, eg 1280x1024, 1600x900, 1280x720, etc.. I can say using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: You can't make a fixed-sized window, you need to dynamically layout the UI depending on dimensions.

Comment: and how i can make that?

Comment: It was/is relatively difficult in Windows API. Then, MFC made these things simpler. I guess, it is peace of cake in Win Forms - just search for corresponding MSDN sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Windows Forms, you should use WPF, it solve that kind of issue. Look at [Resolution independent or monitor size independent WPF apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897849/resolution-independent-or-monitor-size-independent-wpf-apps).

You can with VS'12 create WPF UI with C++/CLI
it can provide an easy integration of your C++ native code.

Comment: And how i can make WPF?